# calling values in a database using column name in sqlite

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a sqlite database with rows of planets name and column having the mass, radius and so on.
Is there a way to call the mass of earth in the form as `Earth.mass` or something similar in python?
I have very little knowledge of SQL as I have just started out learning SQL just for this project, so sorry if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 0):

The Python SQLite module has a connection object that has a [row factory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory) attribute. But don't just blindly copy the example given!  Instead, follow their advice, and use the provided [Row](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Row) class.